# Help me with hook_views_data

Tags: views

I create a simple module to test [`hook_views_data`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_data/7) but may I get some errors
this is my code

in `tungcan.module` file

```
function test_views_api() {
  return array(
    'api' => '3'
  );
}
```

and in `tungcan.views.inc` file

```
function tungcan_views_data() {
  $data = array();
  $data['tungcan']['table']['group'] = t('TungCan');
  $data['tungcan']['table']['basic'] = array(
    'field' => 'tungid',
    'title' => t('Tungcan'),
    'weight' => -100,
    'defaults' => array(
      'field' => 'tungname',
    ),
  );

  $data['tungcan']['tungname'] = array(
    'title' => t('Tung Name'),
    'help' => t('Display name of Tung')
  );

  return $data;
}
```

but when I clear cache, in my Views (add new views or add new Field) doesn't change anything.

Can somebody point out what is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 3):

If the module is tungcan.module, then the implementation of [hook_views_api()](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_api/7) (necessary to load the include files used from the module to integrate with the Views module) should be `tungcan_views_api()`, not `test_views_api()`.

If, vice versa, the module is test.module, then `tungcan_views_data()` should be renamed to `test_views_data()`.